# is vsto still supported for windows desktop applications

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-addins

First of all sorry if this question seems trivial but i have no experience in office development
we have a VSTO addin for MS word developed in c# as a part of windows Desktop application
this addin works fine for office 2013 , when we tried to add it to office 365 , 2019 and 2021 it failed
when i searched for a solution i got confused weather the desktop addins for office still supported or we have to move our work to Office JS ?

i have not tried coding yet , just searching for the problem

Comment: Probably best to start with Microsoft's own statement about VSTO support and how it is tied to each version of Office at, e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/visual-studio-tools-for-office-runtime?view=vs-2022. Because not everyone has the same understanding of what is meant by "support".

Answer (score 2):

> addin works fine for office 2013 , when we tried to add it to office 365 , 2019 and 2021 it failed

VSTO add-ins are supported in all these Office versions.

First of all, whether an installer is used or not, you need to check prerequisites whether all required components were included to the package. See [Deploying a VSTO Solution Using Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/deploying-a-vsto-solution-by-using-windows-installer?view=vs-2022) for more information how to set up a windows installer for VSTO add-ins.

Be sure that VSTO (COM) add-ins are not going to die in near future. Office web add-ins (`OfficeJS`) don't provide so many features, parity between platforms these days, so VSTO add-ins are valid and provide a rich extensibility model for developers.

So, I'd suggest troubleshooting the add-in on the problematic machine. Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the `Startup` event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the `Startup` event handler is executing. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in that has been disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-re-enable-a-vsto-add-in-that-has-been-disabled?view=vs-2022) article.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, VSTO is very much supported in Office 2016, 2019, 2021 and Office 365 (click-to-run). It is a fairly mature technology, so there isn't much new development going on, but it is still supported.